# Limiting the bits in SVM weights

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn

Is it there any way I can limit the number of bits of the weights obtained while solving the linearSVC?
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC

Comment: Define ```number of bits```. Bits set vs. max-range (=number of bits per feature). Especially the first would make the learning-problem non-convex = hard (infeasible to solve optimally). Usually this kind of stuff (in this case more the latter) is approximated through l1 or l2 loss which is available within scikit-learn.

Comment: @sascha there isn't any option of number of bits. Yeah you are right it would make it harder but I don't care about that here.

Comment: Of course there is no option for this as this is not natural. It seems you are missing the basics of SVM-optimization. You also did not respond to my question. And regarding not caring: why trying it if you can't optimize it? Maybe you can't even approximate a good solution. An easy approach would be (still the problems mentioned above): take a QP-formulation of SVM and add additional Integer-based constraints resulting in an MIQP.